# Word for something that is either transparent or opaque, but can describe both

Tags: single-word-requests

This word would cover everything from completely transparent glass to the kind of opaque glass that you would get in a bathroom. I first thought that opaque would cover the definition, but it appears to specifically apply to a material that you can't see through.

Comment: Your title invites the response "Everything in the world". For the question in the body: *translucent* includes (for some purposes) *transparent*. If they are not your purposes, please add more detail.

Comment: @TimLymington Translucent - (of a substance) allowing light, but not detailed shapes, to pass through; semi-transparent. (from [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ss2FVb3NCqyPigano4CgDQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=translucent))

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do you call a window that is neither opaque nor transparent?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74780/what-do-you-call-a-window-that-is-neither-opaque-nor-transparent)

Comment: @WS2 That is for a window that is _neither_ opaque _nor_ transparent. I want something that can be _both_ opaque _or_ transparent.

Comment: How can something be opaque and transparent? Opaque means "not transparent."

Comment: @GermaneJackson Because it isn't opaque and transparent, its opaque _or_ transparent. So the word doesn't describe something that is both, but something that can be either. I guess that adding 'can' into the title isn't clear enough

Comment: Can you explain a meaningful context in which this word would be used? All glass is on a continuum of transparency/opacity. Do you mean a type of glass that has a property of changing from transparent to opaque?  Like a transparent piece of glass that, tilted in a certain way, becomes opaque? I'm struggling to understand what situation would demand this adjective.

Comment: @GermaneJackson Basically, if I had two separate panes of glass, one which is completely transparent and =you can see images clearly, and the other is very opaque, this word would be able to describe them both. Also, it shouldn't be just confined to glass, so you could describe different liquids, like water.

Comment: This makes no sense. You'll have to give a real world example of something that can be one or the other, and give a sentence with a blank in it where you want the wor to be. Do you want a single word for some glass that could be transparent or could be opaque (based on some change in manufacture process)? if so, then the single word is 'glass' and you then specify its 'opacity'. What is the purpose of this one word, to label a database column? Or is it a particular substane you have in mind that changes its opacity?

Comment: @Mitch It makes no sense because you think it has to be both! It doesn't describe something that is both transparent and opaque! You can, however use the word to describe something that is transparent, and something else that is opaque.

Comment: Orfby, no, I get that it isn't opaque and transparent at the same time. You're not talking about one object, you're talking about one kind of thing, of which there are varieties that are transparent and some that are opaque (and some in between I guess). What I don't get is that you're requesting a single word to describe that situation. When two words suffice, eg, either 'opaque glass' or 'transparent glass'. Are you looking for a word '____ glass' that includes both situations? like 'glass with varying levels of opacity'? If so, what makes a single word so necessary?

Comment: @Mitch I want this word so I can ask if a material (don't know why I keep referring to glass) is transparent (can see clearly through) or opaque. Clarification: there is no difference in input between transparent and opaque, it is just a word that if true, can cover both meanings (I hate that one phrase can mean different things in English).

Comment: Unfortunately the edits have gone round in a circle. A single word that can describe both something opaque and something transparent (the two being opposites) and also something in between? *Existent*.

Comment: @TimLymington you wouldn't consider a block of wood as opaque or transparent, or anything in between, but I see that the question is worded very poorly, because I am very bad at explaining things

Comment: Let's suppose that such a word existed and you asked a sales representative, "Is this thing I want to buy, *conflustulent*?"  and suppose the sale rep says, "Yes, it is."  What knowledge have you gained?

Comment: Orfby, reading between the lines, I sense that you may be a non-native speaker of English. If so, is there a term for this in your native language? If not, you probably need to explain further the nuance of this word. Also, do you have an example sentence where this word would fit?

Comment: @Orfby is your word to transparent/opaque similar to what size is to big/small?

Comment: @Mitch I am a native speaker, I'm just quite young and have problems explaining things.

Comment: @Lucky Kind of yes, but it shouldn't be a way of measuring transparency/opaqueness

Comment: @Jim I now know how to explain what a setting in a project does to other people (hopefully). I know I keep pushing the material/glass thing, but I only used it so my point was clearer (which it never was), so I don't actually need a material that fits the quota, more I'm asking someone if their material fits that quota.

Comment: You need to give a lot more explanation then of your situation. Starting with a sample sentence with a blank for where you think the word should go. And then the context and motivation for the sentence.

Comment: @Mitch Putting a sample sentence seems silly because it would literally be "Is this material ______". The context is a configuration file (don't ask) and motivation is that I want to use as few words as possible because saying, "Is it transparent, opaque or anything in-between?" seems over complicated (and I thought it would be easier to find the correct word).

Comment: Without bothering to read all of the comments (the plethora of which hint that *your question is perhaps not clear*), I'm guessing that you might be interested in a word that refers to how transparent or opaque something is. Two words for that quality are *opacity* and *opaqueness*.

Comment: @Orfby - the problem is, that the answer to “*is it transparent, opaque, or anything in between*” ***would be ’Yes’ for every object in the world.***   I think that what you are really looking for is ***opacity*** or ***transparency*** you can choose which attribute you want to emphasize,. *then* you get to put a number in your configuration file between, say, 0 and 100 where 0 opacity = 100 transparency and vice versa.

Comment: Orfby, OK, we're now getting a glimpse of what you need (which is not exactly you are asking for). This is a common difficulty (similar to expecting  a dictionary to tell you how to spell a word when the only way to find it is to  already know how to spell it). You want to ask a short question and have the answer be 'opaque' or 'transparent' (or maybe something in between), right? Then the question would be "What is the opacity?" or what is the degree of opacity?". If so, then you should edit your original question to this. Otherwise, you might have this question closed as 'unclear'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closest I can get would be **"degree of opacity"**.  It can range from no opacity at all (total transparency) to totally opaque (zero transparency).

- Opacity is the measure of impenetrability to electromagnetic or other kinds of radiation, especially visible light. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opacity_(optics))

Comment: I'm pretty sure "opacity" alone would do. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opacity_(optics)

Comment: It is interesting to note that Photoshop uses the term opacity to refer to how much one can see layers under one layer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no word that simultaneously means something opaque and something transparent. The only way this question makes sense is if you're asking for a word that covers degree of transparency/opacity. Otherwise the question is total nonsense or this is an incredibly strange and actually somewhat brilliant troll.

Answer (score 2):

Translucent!-(of a substance) allowing light, but not detailed images, to pass through; semitransparent.
"fry until the onions become translucent"
synonyms:   semitransparent, semiopaque, pellucid, limpid, clear; More

Comment: My God I can't believe all the comments/answers acting all confused like this is a philosophical question... "translucent" is the word MADE for this exact purpose and it's completely standard

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use:

**[optical density](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/optical+density)**:

> (physics) a measure of the extent to which a substance transmits light or other electromagnetic radiation (TFD).

The logic is simple: to see an object on the other side of your material the light has to travel from your side, through the material to that object, and then back to your eye. Higher optical density means that it will be more difficult for light to travel, therefore it will be more difficult for you to see the object.

The optical density of a completely transparent object (100% of light goes straight through) is zero.

---

Two concerns with this word:

- It isn't exactly a single word (I wouldn't call it a compound noun), but it is a **single term**.
- Although dictionary definitions state that it is a term borrowed from physics, scientific discourse regarding physics is the only occasion where you shouldn't use this term. Here's why:

Some dictionaries (e.g. [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/optical-density)) say that this is an old term for two different terms:

[reflection density](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/reflection-density#reflection-density_1)

> (physics) a measure of the extent to which a surface reflects light or other electromagnetic radiation, equal to the logarithm to base ten of the reciprocal of the reflectance D Former name: optical density

and

[transmission density](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/transmission-density#transmission-density_1):

> (physics) a measure of the extent to which a substance transmits light or other electromagnetic radiation, equal to the logarithm to base ten of the reciprocal of the transmittance τ Former name: optical density

(today this is also called absorbance - A)

If you are talking to physicists, they would expect you to know which of these two measures you are talking about. But in other contexts it makes no difference whether the light is diverted (or in an extreme case reflected) - which corresponds to reflection density, or it is absorbed - which corresponds to transmission density, either way it doesn't freely pass through your material, and it makes it difficult to see the object on the other side (or the opposite: if the optical density is low, the light is neither reflected nor absorbed and you see the object on the other side clearly).

---

EDIT (from OP's comments): You would like something that describes the whole range of transparency/opacity from completely transparent to completely non-transparent (completely opaque), but you don't want it to be a measure. I'm afraid that this is not possible - because you are looking for a term to describe one of the two extremes or anything in between. Something that can be scaled, graded - can be measured. It isn't like colour, which is a **hypernym** for red, green, yellow, blue, purple, red, orange etc. because you don't have a whole set of elements from which to choose - you have only two opposite elements (like black/white (light/dark) and all the shades of gray in between).

I therefore stand by my suggestion **optical density** because it can describe the whole range while it doesn't suggest that the object is closer to one end of the scale, it is somewhat more neutral then opacity/transparency (although both of these terms are also quite good).

Comment: @Orfby I'm afraid that your request for the term not to be a measure can't be met. Please see the edit for the rationale :-).

Comment: I didn't know that something can be described as opaque (completely opaque) but not allow any light to pass through, that may be one of the sources of overwhelming confusion from everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is "opacity."

The dictionary definition of it tends to refer to lack of transparency, but this is a good example of why a dictionary is not always the best place for learning language. Unlike "opaque," actual usage of "opacity" often covers a spectrum and not a single state. In other words, if you ask "What is the opacity of this type of plastic?" the range of possibilities includes everything from full opacity to full transparency.

Answer (score 0):

My dictionary has for German lichtdurchlässig (letting light pass through) the words translucent, pervious to light, light-transmissive.

By the way, opaque lets through light. There are garden lamps with opaque bowls, but they light the garden.

Comment: "Translucent" is the word for something that lets light through without being transparent. An opaque object, by definition, cannot let light through.